# Filters params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a filter with a lot of params and i would know the best way to write it in my controller, my conditions work but individually i want know the good way to write it and make it work with all my params with create 9999 conditions like "params.present? && params.present? etc..."

My controller:

```
if params[:room_type].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(room_type: params[:room_type])
    elsif params[:nb_piece].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(nb_piece: params[:nb_piece])
    elsif params[:nb_piece].present? && params[:room_type].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(nb_piece: params[:nb_piece], room_type: params[:room_type])
    elsif params[:location].present?
      @biens = Bien.near(params[:location], 1, units: :km)
    elsif params[:nb_piece].present? && params[:room_type].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(nb_piece: params[:nb_piece]) && Bien.where(room_type: params[:room_type])
    elsif params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(compromis_date: Date.parse(params[:start_date])..Date.parse(params[:end_date]))
    elsif params[:start_price].present? && params[:end_price].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(prix: params[:start_price]..params[:end_price])
    elsif params[:negociateur].present?
      @biens = Bien.where(negociateur: params[:negociateur])
    else
      @biens = Bien.all
    end
```

Comment: Check Filterrific gem http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/active_record_model_api.html or apply simple solution from Justin Weiss: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/

Answer (score 0):

I believe below solution would work for you. I haven't tested it, but something similar should work. Please try it and let me know in comments if you have any concerns with this.

```
params.each do|key, value|
   next if params[key.to_sym].blank?
   @biens = Bien.where(key.to_sym => value)
   break
end
if @biens.blank?
   @biens = Bien.all
end
```